# html file upload as part of another form

Tags: javascript, ajax, file-upload

Idealy I would like to have the following:

```
<form1 ...>

    ...

     <form2 ...>

         //This form uploads a file using AJAX and writes the content into a text field below.

     </form2>

     <input type="text"/>

</form1>
```

Firefox handles this but IE likes to follow the rules of W3C this time and it doesn't really work.

So now I have to handle form2 outside of form1 through javascript. Can you provide some help about how to go about this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't have nested form tags.  What's different about form2?  Does it submit to a different place?  Is the only difference that it's supposed to be submitted via AJAX?

Answer (score 0):

Hook the submit event (from form 1's submit), and use something like [Ajax.Request](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/ajax/request) in Prototype to scrape and send form 2.  You might find [Form.request](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/form/request) useful as well.

TODO:  learn the jQuery way to do it, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try using the YUI library to perform an AJAX file upload?

Here is a great tutorial on how to accomplish this:
http://thecodecentral.com/2007/09/04/asynchronous-file-upload-yuis-approach

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to put the same handler on the submit event of both forms. In it, prevent the default behavior of each submission. Submit `form2` using the `submit` function; then remove it from the DOM. Next, feel free to submit `form1`. Of course, you could use AJAX to submit the forms as well, since you already have the handler placed.